# Cookies Enabled or Disabled

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, cookies

1. I have Disabled cookies for safari browser from settings. and now whenever I am going to login in facebook from my safari browser it's disallowed me.
2. So, My query is that how can I check from my app that cookies are enabled or disabled.
3. Or another thing is there anyway to login through facebook while cookies are disable from settings. From Instagram app it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies is use for storing some information of site. so for next visit that cookies can use directly without user input.

Now in your case if you are not allowing cookies than it will not load your stored info. instead you have to add by your own to proceed.

It does not restrict any site or app.

Comment: It's opening facebook login page from my applicaiton and after inserting my correct id and password when I will press login both will be clear and it won't be login in facebook.